# Raspberry dead?

Tags: power-supply

IN order to change the circuit, I unplugged the pi. 
Now when I plug it again (through micro USB), I've no lights at all.

I tried with several power supply, which work with my phone.

Also I see the expected 5V on the GPIO ports, 3.3 on the other.

Is my raspberry dead? Why?

Comment: It sounds dead.  We can not tell what you have done wrong (and the odds are that you have done something wrong).  Do check that the SD card is properly inserted.  Perhaps work through http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting

Comment: I was testing a mosfet with some 24V. Could this have fried my Pi?

Comment: Any voltage greater than 3V3 connected to a gpio could damage the gpio and the Pi.  Any voltage greater than 6V connected to the 5V or 3V3 rail will damage the Pi.

Comment: Ok, but I read something about a fuse, which reset when being colder, this doesn't apply?

Comment: There is a time resetting polyfuse which triggers when more than 2 amps is fed in via the microUSB socket.  The circuitry following the microUSB socket also has circuitry which may give a little, not a lot, of protection for voltages greater than 6V.  Both of these only apply if you fed the 24V via the microUSB socket.

Comment: Thank you very much for all those clarification. Can you maybe post an answer with all this and I will accept it